# Operations with aggregate functions - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I don't get how to make a subquery with aggregate functions, about how to handle the aggregate functions and use it with others.

This is my code

```
SET DATEFORMAT DMY;
GO

SELECT
      NumeroD AS 'Bill '
    , Descrip1 AS 'Product Description' 
    , MAX(ExistAnt) AS 'Ex. Act.'
    , MIN((ExistAnt)) AS 'Ex. Act.'
    , SUM(CASE
        WHEN TipoFac = 'A' THEN Amount
        WHEN TipoFac = 'B' THEN -Amount END) AS 'Total Amount'

    , CASE
        WHEN TipoFac = 'A' THEN (Amount*Price) END AS 'Total Sale'
    , CASE
        WHEN TipoFac = 'A' THEN (Amount*Cost) END AS 'Total Cost'
    , CASE
        WHEN TipoFac = 'A' THEN 'Total Sale' - 'Total Cost'  END AS 'Total Utility'
    , CASE
        WHEN TipoFac = 'A' THEN ('Total Utility' * 100) / 'Total Sale' END AS '% Util' 
    , NroLineaC
    , DEsComp

FROM
    SAITEMFAC
WHERE
    DateE BETWEEN '05/07/2022' AND '05/07/2022 23:59:59'
    AND codubic = '0010-01' 
    AND CodItem = '11001'
GROUP BY
    Coditem
    , NumeroD
    , Descrip1
    , TipoFac
    , Cantidad
    , Precio 
    , Costo
```

When I click the F5 key, I get an error:

> The data types varchar and varchar are incompatible in the subtract operator

Could somebody please guide me about what steps to follow?

I appreciate your help.

PS: maybe using a CTE?

Comment: single quotes makes from all columns names strings use double quotes or [] instead, when using it to use it in mathimatical functions

Comment: Firstly, don't use single quotes (`'`) for aliases. Single quotes are for literal strings, not delimit identifying object names. They only work when you define them, no where else; `ORDER BY 'value'` would *not* order by a column aliased as `'value'`, it would order by the `varchar` literal `'value'` (so would effectively not order at all). Also some syntaxes with literal string aliases are deprecated. Stick to object and alias names that don't need delimit identifying, and if you *must* delimit identify them use the T-SQL identifier, brackets (`[]`), or ANSI-SQL's, double quotes (`"`).

Comment: Next, you *can't* reference a column by its alias in the same scope; you would either need to use a derived table, a CTE, or *repeat* the expression. `SELECT 1 AS A, A + 1 AS B;` will return the error `Invalid column name 'A'.`, not `1` and `2`. `SELECT A, A + 1 FROM (SELECT 1 AS A) DT;` would work fine though.

Comment: Lastly, don't use logic like `DateE BETWEEN '05/07/2022' AND '05/07/2022 23:59:59'`; in this case it'll exclude any rows *after* `2022-07-05T23:59:59.0000000` and *before* `2022-07-06T00:00:00.0000000`; so almost an entire second of time. Use `>=` and `<` logic for explicit boundaries, not `BETWEEN`, and *don't* use ambiguous date formats in your literal strings: `DateE >= '20220705' AND DateE < '20220706'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, to repeat a lot of my comments.

Don't use literal strings for aliases; this is a bad habit and it doesn't work as people think. Take the query `SELECT [name] AS 'DatabaseName' FROM sys.databases ORDER BY 'DatabaseName';` This does *not* `ORDER BY` the column aliased as `'DatabaseName'`, instead it orders by the **literal** `varchar` value `'DatabaseName'`; thus is has no order, as the literal value is the same for *every* row. Ideally, don't use object and aliases that require delimit identifying. If you *must* then either use T-SQL's delimit identify, brackets (`[]`), or the ANSI-SQL delimit identifier, double quotes (`"`).

Next, you *can't* reference a column by it's alias in the same query scope *apart* from in the `ORDER BY`; `SELECT 1 AS A, A + 1 AS B;` will give an invalid column error, as the column `A` isn't defined. You would need to repeat the expression again to use that expression in the same scope. If you need to reference a column by its alias, you need to use a derived table or a CTE:

```sql
--Derived table
SELECT A,
       A + 1
FROM (SELECT 1 AS A) DT;

--CTE
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT 1 AS A)
SELECT A,
       A+1 AS B
FROM CTE;
```

Finally, `DateE BETWEEN '05/07/2022' AND '05/07/2022 23:59:59'` is bad for a couple of reasons; it misses off the last second of the day, and its an ambiguous date format. Use `>=` and `<` logic and an unambiguous format; for T-SQL that is `yyyyMMdd` and `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss(.nnnnnnn)`. So instead you have `DateE >= '20220705' AND DateE < '20220706'`.

---

Now, onto your problem. As I mentioned, there are a couple of options open to use. Personally, I would suggest just repeating the expressions here, as they aren't complicated:

```sql
SELECT NumeroD AS Bill, --Don't use literal strings for aliases
       Descrip1 AS ProductDescription, --Don't use object names/aliases that require delimit
       MAX(ExistAnt) AS [Ex. Act.],    --If you must, then use brackets ([]) or double quotes (")
       MIN(ExistAnt) AS [Ex. Act.],  --but, ideally use camelCase, PascalCase, or snake_case instead (I prefer PascalCase)
       --The above 2 columns have the same alias; that can't be right
       SUM(CASE WHEN TipoFac = 'A' THEN Amount
                WHEN TipoFac = 'B' THEN -Amount
           END) AS TotalAmount,
        CASE WHEN TipoFac = 'A' THEN (Amount*Price) END AS TotalSale,
        CASE WHEN TipoFac = 'A' THEN (Amount*Cost) END AS TotalCost,
        CASE WHEN TipoFac = 'A' THEN (Amount*Price) - (Amount*Cost) END AS TotalUtility, --Repeat the expression
        CASE WHEN TipoFac = 'A' THEN (((Amount*Price) - (Amount*Cost)) * 100) / (Amount*Price)  END AS PercentageUtil,
        NroLineaC,
        DEsComp
FROM dbo.SAITEMFAC --Always schema qualify your objects
WHERE DateE >= '20220705' AND DateE < '20220706' --Use better date boundaries, not BETWEEN
  AND codubic = '0010-01'
  AND CodItem = '11001'
GROUP BY Coditem,
         NumeroD,
         Descrip1,
         TipoFac,
         Cantidad,
         Precio,
         Costo;
```

If you "had to" reference them by their alias, or for more complicated expressions, I would use a CTE. This isn't needed for what you have here, but I'll show you anyway. As you have a nested reference, you'll actually need to use two CTEs:

```sql
WITH SalesCost AS(
    SELECT NumeroD AS Bill, 
           Descrip1 AS ProductDescription,
           MAX(ExistAnt) AS ExAct1,   
           MIN(ExistAnt) AS ExAct2, --These cannot have the same name in a CTE/Derived table
           SUM(CASE WHEN TipoFac = 'A' THEN Amount
                    WHEN TipoFac = 'B' THEN -Amount
               END) AS TotalAmount,
            CASE WHEN TipoFac = 'A' THEN (Amount*Price) END AS TotalSale,
            CASE WHEN TipoFac = 'A' THEN (Amount*Cost) END AS TotalCost,
            NroLineaC,
            DEsComp
    FROM dbo.SAITEMFAC --Always schema qualify your objects
    WHERE DateE >= '20220705' AND DateE < '20220706' --Use better date boundaries, not BETWEEN
      AND codubic = '0010-01'
      AND CodItem = '11001'
    GROUP BY Coditem,
             NumeroD,
             Descrip1,
             TipoFac,
             Cantidad,
             Precio,
             Costo),
Utility AS(
    SELECT Bill,
           ProductDescription,
           ExAct1,
           ExAct2,
           TotalAmount,
           TotalSale,
           TotalCost,
           TotalSale - TotalCost AS TotalUtility, --No need for the CASE here, as it's already handled
           NroLineaC,
           DEsComp
    FROM SalesCost)
SELECT Bill,
       ProductDescription,
       ExAct1,
       ExAct2,
       TotalAmount,
       TotalSale,
       TotalCost,
       TotalUtility,
       (TotalUtility * 100) / TotalSales AS PercentageUtility,
       NroLineaC,
       DEsComp
FROM Utility;
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach is to re-type your logic instead of using aliases (which won't work without a CTE or derived table), ie replace this:

```
, CASE
    WHEN TipoFac = 'A' THEN (Amount*Price) END AS 'Total Sale'
, CASE
    WHEN TipoFac = 'A' THEN (Amount*Cost) END AS 'Total Cost'
, CASE
    WHEN TipoFac = 'A' THEN 'Total Sale' - 'Total Cost'  END AS 'Total Utility'
```

With this:

```
, CASE
    WHEN TipoFac = 'A' THEN (Amount*Price) END AS 'Total Sale'
, CASE
    WHEN TipoFac = 'A' THEN (Amount*Cost) END AS 'Total Cost'
, CASE
    WHEN TipoFac = 'A' THEN (Amount*Price) - (Amount*Cost)  END AS 'Total Utility'
```